# Regulating 4s 18650 battery to 12V or use 5s instead?

Tags: power

I'm working on a power distribution board which is going to distribute to several other devices/boards.
Due to the high current requierment of the all the devices in total (about 29A - mix of 5V, 12V, 3.3V - mainly most current at 12V), I've decided to have 3 inputs to my board from the same battery. (my connectors were limited to 13A each)

Now, the 4s 18650s (not sure how many in parallel yet.) will have a nominal voltage of about 14.8V. Thus, I need to buck this down to 12V for each of my inputs.

Now the issue I have is that I can't seem to find many buck converters that will operate with an input of about 14.8 and give me 12V out, they're too close.

So I'm thinking, if I go with a 5s instead and then I'll have 18.5V nominal, I can easily buck that down with an IC such as the MAX20745. Would that seem like a reasonable solution?

MAX20745: https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/power/switching-regulators/MAX20745.html

Comment: The idea of needing to put a buck regulator on a 29 ampere supply hints at a design that is not fully thought through.  Motor drivers, for example, are preferably designed to handle a variation in supply voltage themselves, and effectively fold the "regulation" into their control of the motor itself.  And any high current lower voltage regulators should be selected to tolerate your pack voltage variation directly.  What are your actual loads, specifically?  And what are their specifications?  Have you ever designed a circuit board or regulator supporting even just a few amperes?

Comment: Also, can any of your loads feed power back to the supply?  For example a motor driver may end up doing so, and your buck regulator might not tolerate that.

Comment: @ChrisStratton  It's part of the FSAE Formula Student competition for an eV car. This board provides power to the low-voltage parts on the car. 5V loads would be two microcontroller boards running diferent sensors and a GPS module with a total load of just under 3A (from both). The 12V loads are high power LEDs (6W for one, 3W for the other). The main 12V loads are 0.68A fans (about 20). The remaining are 2 water cooling pumps at 12V (2.5A each) and 1 radiator fan at 7A.

Comment: Whoever is doing the *motive* power systems for your electric car would probably have a lot of relevant thoughts - you really shouldn't try to do this without consulting them, and it's a little bit odd that you want to run all of this stuff off a unique pack.   If the motive team won't give you a power bus (think about how every production EV would have a 12v accessory supply...) you should probably consider your loads uniquely.  For example, look at what that radiator fan's motor and or driver can actually take, or replace them with more flexible solutions.  Consider a regulator per load...

Comment: @ChrisStratton A regulator per load I see. That was my plan for the 5V and 3.3V devices. I just thought that instead of driving each of my 12V more hungry loads with their own regulator that I could just use a higher current capable buck converter for each of my battery input. Thanks for the input, I'll do so more research on using a regulator per load.

Comment: As you're researching make sure you check the regulator efficiency graphs wherever you can find or make them.  Some regulators operate at decent efficiency only when close to full load.  ~90% is reasonable for well thought out regulator choices, so be careful about multiple conversions on large loads.  Even if each conversion is 90% efficient, the end output is only 81% efficient.  For variable loads, you can look for topologies that have flatter efficiency graphs (usually PFM drive instead of PWM) and with this type of driver, ganging up variable loads on a supply isn't a horrible idea.

Comment: @KH Yeah I noticed that in some data sheets. Some regulators drop to 50% efficiency at some load current values - I was quite surprised.

Comment: @ChrisStratton One last question. I'm assuming for things like microcontrollers, I can just straight up use a 5V step-down buck converter to drive that. For the higher loads like the pump or fans, I'll stick with a regulator per load like you suggested, is there anything else I should watch out for those pumps/fans? I'd like to keep this design as simple as possible. I know traces on a PCB are gonna be much wider now.

Comment: If your components are spaced out a lot too, higher voltage requires smaller wire, so individual regulators would allow you to run your source voltage backbone all over (or tie in to the existing one would make more sense) and convert the power you need where you need it.

Comment: For the pumps and fans, I think you really need to like at the *type* of motor.  For something brushed, I'd just PWM it.  For a brushless, preferably find a driver that can deal with the voltage you have available.   Also look at the *actual* ratings of anything off-the-shelf automotive - in that context "12 volts" is a sort of nominal consumer spec, the actual electrical system of a car can be higher when the engine is running and spike (or be two-battery jumped) quite a bit higher than that.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I'll look into that. Thank you so much for the information. Someone else is actually designing the fan driver board and pump driver board and I'm supposed to provide them with the constant 12V. I'll speak to them. Thank you so much.

Comment: @KH I'd love to run a 12V power plane but we've only got budget for 2-layer boards so I'm gonna dedicate both of them to GND and just run my 12V around on traces -> 3 split traces  - one from each input. Thanks for the help

Comment: If you don't have budget for power-worthy boards, and almost regardless if you are only making one or two cars, you should perhaps just use terminal blocks.

Comment: @ChrisStratton terminal blocks? Those screw terminal things? And just use wires instead?

Comment: Yes.  Big ones.  And please have a fault protection right at the battery.